# Use color names specified in data as fill color in geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, fill

I have a data frame (*freqOvertimeHourlyData*) like this:

```
     HOURS INTERVAL BARCOLOR
1     147    16-17  "green"
2     150    17-18  "green"
3     144    18-19  "blue"
4     149    19-20  "red"
5     139    20-21  "red"
6     101    21-22  "red"
```

Is there a way to create a barplot, using `geom_bar`, with fill color according to the actual color names explicitly specified as a variable in the data set (column BARCOLOR)? My current plot is made like this:

```
ggplot(freqOvertimeHourlyData, aes(x = INTERVAL, y = HOURS))+
geom_histogram(stat = "identity")+
theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you wish to use the raw values, without scaling, for your aesthetics, then `scale_identity` can be used. Using "DF" from @Sandy Muspratt's answer:

```
ggplot(DF, aes(x = INTERVAL, y = HOURS, fill = BARCOLOR))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  scale_fill_identity()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot saved me lots of headache atm

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure `BARCOLOR` is a factor.

You need to tell ggplot to fill the bars with colour - `fill = BARCOLOR` will do that.

But it doesn't matter to `ggplot` what the contents of `BARCOLOR` is, `ggplot` will use its default colours.

You need to set values, that is, your colours, in `scale_fill_manual()`

```
library(ggplot2)

DF = read.table(text = '
     HOURS INTERVAL BARCOLOR
1     147    16-17  "blue"
2     150    17-18  "green"
3     144    18-19  "blue"
4     149    19-20  "red"
5     139    20-21  "black"
6     101    21-22  "green" ', header = TRUE)

str(DF)   # Check BARCOLOR is a factor

ggplot(DF, aes(x = INTERVAL, y = HOURS, fill = BARCOLOR))+
   geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
   theme(legend.position = "none") +
   scale_fill_manual(values = levels(DF$BARCOLOR))
```

[image]